# Vega statistics Get Transform result as an object

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I want to use transform in Vega and get results as an object. Similar to the example in the link:
https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/aggregate/
I want to get the output, example: [{"v": 2, "s": 6, "m": 2}], and use it in other calculation. So I don't want to load to visualization ex. chart. I want to get the resulted object and work on it. Can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. For Vega spec, just include the data block with transforms.
2. Run Vega the usual way to create a Vega "view".
3. In javascript, use [Vega View API's *data* method](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/) to get the transformed dataset object.

Here is a complete working example (html and javascript) using the example from Vega [*aggregate*](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/aggregate/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Vega5</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vis"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://vega.github.io/vega/vega.js"></script>

  <script>
    
    let vegaSpec = {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
      
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "mydata",
          "values" : [
              {"foo": 1, "bar": 1},
              {"foo": 1, "bar": 2},
              {"foo": null, "bar": 3}
            ],
          "transform": [
            {
              "type": "aggregate",
              "fields": ["foo", "bar", "bar"],
              "ops": ["valid", "sum", "median"],
              "as": ["v", "s", "m"]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    let vegaView = new vega.View(vega.parse(vegaSpec))
      .logLevel(vega.Warn)
      .initialize("#vis")
      .renderer("svg")
      .hover()
      .run();

    let my_transformed_data = vegaView.data("mydata");  //  vega view API
    console.log(my_transformed_data);
  </script>
</html>
```

console.log output:
[image: console.log output]